# Склонение названия организации

Tags: морфология

Как правильно написать: ООО "Судоходная компания" готовО предложить или готовА предложить?

Answer (score 7):

В устной речи оба варианта произносятся одинаково (безударная позиция). А в письменной речи нормы нужно соблюсти. *ООО "Судоходная компания" готово предложить*

Answer (score 3):

Если эта фраза из рекламной брошюры, то рекомендую в начале добавить местоимение "наше".

*Наше ООО "Судоходная компания" готово предложить...*

Иначе соотнести "ООО" с "готово", действительно проблематично и вместо рассмотрения предложений, человек будет объяснять вашу орфографию.

Answer (score 3):

(Общество с ограниченной ответственностью) "Судоходная компания". В этом словосочетании главным компонентом является (Общество с ограниченной ответственностью),  а зависимым --- "Судоходная компания", как имя собственное, как название Общества. Включенные в предложение, эти компоненты выполняют синтаксические функции: (Общество с ограниченной ответственностью, или ООО) --- подлежащее предложения, "Судоходная компания" --- определение-приложение при этом подлежащем,  а сказуемое --- готово предложить (краткое имя прилагательное + нулевая связка + глагол - инфинитив). В предложении коррелируют в среднем роде, в единственном числе подлежащее и сказуемое,а более точно: ОБЩЕСТВ-О(часть подлежащего) и ГОТОВ-О (часть сказуемого).

Вывод. ООО "Судоходная компания" готовО предложить...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, по идее "готово" — ведь определяющим тут является все-таки ООО (общество с ограниченной ответственностью). Хотя просится, конечно, женский род, потому что в уме человек не станет расшифровывать аббревиатуру.

Comment: Согласна. Если бы употреблялось без ООО, просто " Судоходная компания", то тогда "готова".